# Client Side Infinite Scrolling JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll, ondemand

I'm trying to make a [twitter like - LazyLoad] comments page for my web site. 
I found a lot of plugins that do this using PHP [for the server side].

I tried: [Sausage](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?nrq68TRZ), [Jquery4u](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/), [Infinite Ajax Scroll](http://www.fieg.nl/infinite-ajax-scroll-a-jquery-plugin) .. & there a lot more [here](http://designsuperstars.net/10-cool-infinite-scrolling-effects-that-can-enhance-your-websites-navigation/)

I use C# so I just want a plugin that works on client side with Static Data, so that I can handle it later using Json.

Are there any plugins for Continuos scrolling that work like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Masonry allows you to do this including a fancy way of showing the data. you can grab the loader from that code

http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html

Comment: But for the scrolling plugin, it uses Infinite Scroll which still uses PHP to get the data from DB.

Comment: my bad, i thought it had an offline method as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

One of the examples you had shown could work well with any server-side technology, including ASP.NET.

Just some basic HTML to start:

```
<div id="posts">
   <div class="item">Starting content</div>
   <div id="loadmore" style="display: none"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>
</div>
```

And a small piece of jQuery code (you don't need a plugin to do it):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        $("#loadmore").show();

        $.ajax({
          url: "loadmore.aspx",
          contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        ).done(function(html) {
            if (html) {
                $("#posts").append(html);
                $("#loadmore").hide();
            } else
                $("#loadmore").html("No more posts to show.");
        });
    }
});
```

Since the ASPX code renders as HTML, the content can be appended right on the #posts wrapper. You'll of course need to adjust a little the code, passing some parameters to your ASPX to know how many posts to retrieve and starting from what post... But the client-side code isn't the problem here anymore.